# one-form expression

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms

For a smooth function f , one form $df$ is defined as $df(Z)= fd(Z)$.

Prove that:

$$ df= \frac{ \partial f}{\partial z}dz+ \frac{\partial f} {\partial \bar z} d\bar z$$

My attempt:

One-form $df$ can be expressed in terms of basis as:

$$df=adz+ bd \bar z$$
$$Z(f)= (\frac{ \partial f}{\partial z}, \frac{\partial f} {\partial \bar z})$$
$$df(Z)=(a,b)$$
Thus,
$$ df= \frac{ \partial f}{\partial z}dz+ \frac{\partial f} {\partial \bar z} d\bar z$$

I am really confused, if my attempt is correct. Any help will be very appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: You haven't written much down here. What are the *definitions* of $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}$ you're starting with? Also, your $df(Z) = f d(Z)$ makes no sense at all.

Comment: @TedShifrin , Sorry for the confusion. In page 7 and 8, the definition is defined.https://jubcomplexanalysis2017.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/complexanalysis1.pdf . Basically, they are differential operators in complex basis.

Comment: The definitions (with typos) are actually on p. 5. To make a convincing proof, you need to start with $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$ and change basis to $dz, d\bar z$ ($dz = dx+i\,dy$, $d\bar z=dx-i\,dy$) and see that the coefficients are precisely what's given on p. 5 for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do we still have to use $df(Z)=fd(Z)$?

Comment: I have no idea what that's supposed to mean. But it looks like garbage to me.

Comment: Ok, great. I proved it with your hints.

Comment: Great! Well done. I'm not sure about those notes ... :D